# Outputting formatted PDFs and RTFs in Java code

Tags: java, pdf-generation, rtf

I'm looking to write some PDF and RTF files from my java app.  I can use templates and so these would tend to vary between letter style reports where I replace some placeholders with data, to repeating table formats where there is a table/subform dynamically added for each row of data.

Is there a good tool to do all these things, to cut down the learning curve,

write rtf and pdf format
read template in, replace placeholders & save document
create more traditional repeating report ?

I read in a different answer that Jasper may do the job but it was quite an old question so I thought I'd see if it was still a good tool ?

Comment: *read template in, replace placeholders* - in case of pdfs that is a bad idea. Pdfs are not made for editing content.

Comment: Yes but the template can be any format.  For example if it were a dotNet app I would probably do it all with MS Word file templates and then finish with a SaveAs x.pdf or x.rtf.  I had the impression that Jasper might offer this capability but was hoping someone might be able to confirm/deny this before I throw time at it?!  Maybe Apache OpenOffice is a better option for example?  To be honest I have no experience with any of them and I'm hoping to make sure I don't waste too many hours/days investigating libraries which don't offer the functionality I need.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Having thrashed about for a while I would add to the number of people who say Jasper Reports.  Reasons for this include simplicity, free, OO/Uno out of the box is 32 bit and I'm running on a 64 bit windows environment.  Apose looked like a good alternative (implementation of) to OO/Uno but as it costs hard cash I didn't evaluate it.

Not sure this answer is worth much but as no one else has answered it I thought I chuck my experience in and 'close' the question